# Another way to say "fulfill your dream"

Tags: phrase-requests, metaphors

What's another phrase or metaphor that means "to fulfill your dream" or "make your dreams a reality?"

Comment: +1 great question. I just wondering, why do you need to know this? Because I did too.

Comment: I was just writing something and needed to say it differently. I don't even remember what it was.

Comment: I just found **"Let's make it happen!"** as asking in English chat room. Maybe it helps you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- achieve one's ambition
- meet your desires
- fulfill your wish / make your wish come true

Looking for a metaphor, one option is:

> To describe someone's achievement as a **feather in their cap** means
>     that it is something they can be proud of.
>     "The overwhelming victory of the team was a feather in the cap for the
>     new manager."
>
> Source: *[Success/Failure Idioms](http://www.learn-english-today.com/idioms/idiom-categories/success-failure-idioms.htm)*

Answer (score 3):

Well, the word ***[actualize](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/actualize)*** means *to make real*. Specifically, ***[self-actualization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-actualization)*** is a term used by psychological theorists to describe the process by which a person reaches his full potential. There's a subtle difference between fulfilling dreams and reaching max potential, so you could say ***actualize your aspirations***.

Comment: Can I use *actualize* in place of *make this dream true* as well, or just **"actualize it"**, if I don't need to specifying *dream*? Because consider, I just mentioned about that dream.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to say it would be "to realize your dream".

Comment: Thanks but I'm looking for a phrase in a different metaphor realm.

Answer (score -2):

How about in the grasp of your fingers?

Comment: That does not seem to capture what he wants. Perhaps, *to be in his grasp* would work but not *in the grasp of your fingers* which to me sounds like the beginning of an idiom where you **lose** the dream.