# Can wishes come true?

Tags: phrases, expressions, phrase-usage

The common phrase to express that you want someone to exactly get what they wish for is, as far as I know:

> May your **dreams** come true

Can you also say?

> May your **wishes** come true

I have never heard it before, only the *dreams* version.

Is using *wishes* acceptable and if yes, how widespread is it?

Also: Is there a difference in meaning between these two phrases?

Comment: "May your wished be _fulfilled_" is what I have heard so far...

Comment: Very similar: [How to use “come true” for something other than hopes and dreams and wishes?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/325411); also related: [Looking for a Verb / Idiom to Make a Wish Come True](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/163609), [Dreams come true or they are fulfilled. What about 'hopes'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/153264), [Another way to say “fulfill your dream”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43955)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can wishes come true?

Yes, they can. Google returns about 424,000 results for "wish come true".

There is a movie named [*A Wish Come True*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4146410/).

Google Books shows about 34,400 results for the same phrase, among them at least two books titled *Wish Come True* and many others with similar titles such as *Make My Wish Come True*, *Miami Fellas: A Mob Wish Come True*, *The Wish Come True Cat*, *Make a Wish Come True* and more - and all that's just from the first page.

Elvis Presley sang *[My Wish Came True](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=61QTqF9qAow)* in 1957. You can't ask for a better confirmation than that.

Answer (score 2):

*May your wishes come true*. It's acceptable.

*Wishes* in this context would be a synonym for *dreams*.

There is no significant difference.

*May your wishes be fulfilled*. It's probably better this way.